# What is the reason for wrong cmd ouput for mvn --version after installation?

Tags: maven, installation, command-prompt

I have installed **Maven 3.3.3**. Using **JDK 1.6** and OS as **Windows Vista**. But, on command prompt, unable to get proper version details of the maven. **What may be wrong ?** Environment variables (**as system variables**) are set as follows :-

```
    M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven 3.3.3\apache-maven-3.3.3
    MAVEN_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven 3.3.3\apache-maven-3.3.3
    added in PATH as C:\Program Files\Maven 3.3.3\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
    MAVEN_OPTS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

```
    C:\>mvn --version
```

```
    Output is as :-

    Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
               (to execute a class)
       or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
               (to execute a jar file)

    where options include:
        -client       to select the "client" VM
        -server       to select the "server" VM
        -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                      The default VM is client.

        -cp 
        -classpath 
                      A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                      and ZIP archives to search for class files.
        -D=
                      set a system property
        -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                      enable verbose output
        -version      print product version and exit
        -version:
                      require the specified version to run
        -showversion  print product version and continue
        -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                      include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
        -? -help      print this help message
        -X            print help on non-standard options
        -ea[:...|:]
        -enableassertions[:...|:]
                      enable assertions
        -da[:...|:]
        -disableassertions[:...|:]
                      disable assertions
        -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                      enable system assertions
        -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                      disable system assertions
        -agentlib:[=]
                      load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                        see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
        -agentpath:[=]
                      load native agent library by full pathname
        -javaagent:[=]
                      load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

        -splash:
                      show splash screen with specified image
```

Comment: `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME`  are not needed. You only need to make the bin folder part of `PATH`. Have you correctly set `JAVA_HOME` pointing to a JDK? After changing the environment variables have you reopen the console?

Comment: yes, I have reopened the console.(Infact, restarted the system) Still, it's giving the same output.

Comment: I assume your JAVA_HOME does not correctly point to a JDK...? BTW: Can you try simply to remove `MAVEN_OPTS` as the first step...just to see if this is the cause?

Comment: Thanks...the problem got resolved. Actually, Maven 3.3.3 doesn't go with JDK 1.6. So, either I had to use JDK 7 (for 32 bits) or Maven previous versions compatible with JDK 1.6. So, right now its working nicely with Maven 3.2.5 and jdk 1.6

Comment: That Maven 3.3.X needs Java 7 is marked in the [Release notes](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/).

Comment: What is the latest maven version to support with jdk 1.6 ?